# USSD gives Invalid Number

Tags: android, ussd

I am trying to write an app in Android Studio using API 22 that will run a USSD code when I tap a button. Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button buttonT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.FITMO);
    buttonT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do something in response to button click
        }
    });

    Button buttonS = (Button)findViewById(R.id.FISPR);
    buttonS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:*"+ Uri.encode("#") + "*" + Uri.encode("#") + "34777" + Uri.encode("#") + "*" + Uri.encode("#") + "*"));
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

However when I run that code, it opens up a call window and "Invalid number" appears at the top. Any idea how to get the USSD code to run ? The code in question is * # * # 3477 # * # *

Answer (score 0):

You must use this format:

```
*3477*token1*token2*tokenN#
```